# PHP string comparison with zero

Tags: php

I need to write an if condition to detect blank string on PHP. But the variable may get numbers also. So I write the condition like follows. While the variable get the value zero "0" as number the condition detect it as blank `""`

```
$string = array_search("value match", $array);   //$string = 0;

if($string == "")
{
    echo "not equal";
}
```

Is it a bug on PHP? How we can detect for blank value (not null) for a variable which may have numbers or string?

Comment: `$string` is not a string but an integer. And that [`0 == ""` is intended behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

Comment: Could try: if ($string != "" && $string != 0) { } // GOOD

Comment: For further detail following is the function used to get the value of variable `$string = array_search("value match", $array);`. If there is no search match i have to detect it by if condition.

Comment: Have you tried `$string !== false` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: yes it works `$string === false` then how `0` escape from equal to false?. Any how your idea works for my requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `array_search` you will need to check for false:

```
if($string !== false) //Note !== rather than != (stops 0 equating to false)
```

Otherwise 0 will be treated as 'falsy', even though it's a valid return value (first element/key)

Comment: This is correct I thing small modification needed to match the code in question like follows `if($string === false)`. Thanks for the working solution and the proper explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ($string === "") { //With three equality signs
}
```

That's because both `0` and `""` evaluates to `empty()`. It's not a bug, but a side effect of loose typing.

Comment: This fail to detect ""

Comment: How comes? It's a direct comparison to `""` (`"" === ""` will return `true`, of course), how can it fail? It will not detect `0`, however. For this, you have to use `$string === 0` which will check, if `$string` *is* a number *and* exactly 0.

Comment: Following is the function i used to get value `$string = array_search("value match", $array);`. If there is no search match I have to detect it by if condition.